# Implementing discord bot joining logic via oauth: looking for solution on how to join my bot onto a guild

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to add the logic onto my discord bot to add it to a guild however I can't figure out how to do this.

The first thing I tried was to create an algorithm to join a discord server with an oauth.

```py
# an redrected url look like this https://www.example.com/?code=w1WuVLRAqsgBShI7iSlZXCTKlTXBKO&guild_id=1028775661361430648&permissions=71680
# an redrected url look like this https://www.example.com/?code=w1WuVLRAqsgBShI7iSlZXCTKlTXBKO&guild_id=1028775661361430648&permissions=71680
@app.get("/bot-added")
async def bot_added():
    code = request.args.get("code")
    g_id = request.args.get("guild_id")
    guild  = await bot.fetch_guild(g_id)
    g_invites = guild.invites()
    invites_q = []
            
    invites = asyncio.gather(invites_q)
    for invite in invites:
        if not isinstance(invite, HTTPException):
            # join server invite(invite)
            pass
```

While writing this code, I noticed that there are no function/method to join an invite.

While looking online for a solution I found a stackoverflow thread saying you could do a requests to the discord api directly. This solution seem to not be a great alternative due to the possibility of my bot being banned.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hey buddy, I downvoted your question because Luke told you that it wasnt possible and you refused to believe him for some reason.

Comment: I did believed him. My point is that they could have given more explanation by giving a example.

Comment: There is nothing to explain, they physically cant do it. How do you give an example of nothing?

Comment: You show an URL with word in capital to mark what you need to fill in. As example here's a google search: google.co.ck/q?=SEARCH_TERM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the settings of the discord dashboard, I found out I had to disable the following option in order to add the bot to my server:
`REQUIRES OAUTH2 CODE GRANT`

Answer (score 1):

Bots cannot join servers. They must be added *to* a server by an admin.

As example to add a bot with the permission 255 you would do this:
`https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=bot&permissions=255`

Make sure you replace CLIENT_ID with your client ID.

Comment: Is there another way I can make the bot join the server? Each time I add it via the generated oauth link my bot is not added onto my discord.

Comment: Hey buddy, I downvoted your post because I believe you should have given more explanation.

Comment: Thx for the downvote, I believe the correct link would be https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=bot&permissions=8

Replace CLIENT_ID with the one your bot uses and it should work, just make sure you are admin on the server you're trying to add it to